# How to only allow services in nginx's location on the same network

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

I have a NGINX webserver (reverse proxy) and a couple of services behind it. With **docker compose** I can simply spin everything up. No problems so far. However, in my nginx.conf I have one **location**  which should only be accessible by these services

```
 location ~ /magic {
    allow 172.0.0.0/24;
    deny all;
    ...
 }
```

As long as docker compose uses 172.0.0.0/24 ip addresses this works fine. However, I run my images on different machine which use different ip ranges (192.168.1.0/24).

So I was thinking, is there maybe a way to only allow access from services which have an ip address in the same range as the NGINX server. So I tried:

```
allow $server_addr/24;
```

which unfortunately gives an error, telling me that it is an invalid ip address.

I also tried

```
 location ~ /magic {
    map $server_addr $allowed_subnet {
      ~^(?<subnet>\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\.\d+$ $subnet.0/24;
    }
    allow $allowed_subnet;
```

Also not valid. Any suggestions how I can achieve this? Or should